# C# Programs installed array for text file

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, outputstream

Im building a fake Jarvis in C#.

This is the actual code: http://nosliwmichael.blogspot.com/2013/07/jarvis-in-c.html?m=1

My program runs fine and yes before you ask mine is slightly changed but not enough for it to change my problem.

I am trying to generate a list of programs every time the program opens to a .txt file. The way this program works is Jarvis reads a text file for interpreting your speech. It is basically just windows 8 tts but with your own preset definitions. I know there is a way to do this but I cannot seem to make the connection in C#

The idea is it would allow Jarvis to open programs without them being preset.

Also any other suggestions are welcome but I am doing this for my own entertainment so they are not needed.

Original program by:
Michael C.
Youtube link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3oq5uvGGkk

Comment: also I believe this shouldn't be an issue but are you allowed to have multiple grammar files or would I have to move the 'open' commands to the same file used beforehand